# Understanding a lambda construct that contains dot followed by brackets

Tags: kotlin

This is the function declaration for rememberCoilPainter:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberCoilPainter(
    request: Any?,
    imageLoader: ImageLoader = CoilPainterDefaults.defaultImageLoader(),
    shouldRefetchOnSizeChange: ShouldRefetchOnSizeChange = ShouldRefetchOnSizeChange { _, _ -> false },
    requestBuilder: (ImageRequest.Builder.(size: IntSize) -> ImageRequest.Builder)? = null,
    fadeIn: Boolean = false,
    fadeInDurationMs: Int = LoadPainterDefaults.FadeInTransitionDuration,
    @DrawableRes previewPlaceholder: Int = 0,
): LoadPainter<Any> {

}
```

The line of code I am having difficulty understanding is:

`requestBuilder: (ImageRequest.Builder.(size: IntSize) -> ImageRequest.Builder)? = null`

A dot appears after Builder followed by `(size: IntSize)`

This is the first time I've seen this construct in Kotlin and am not sure how to interpret it. This is a lambda. Normally the dot after an object refers to a sub component of a class or a package. But the ( ) after the dot isn't clear.

How do I implement the requestBuilder parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function with receiver type as described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types

> Function types can optionally have an additional receiver type, which is specified before a dot in the notation: the type A.(B) -> C represents functions that can be called on a receiver object of A with a parameter of B and return a value of C. Function literals with receiver are often used along with these types.

It could be tricky to understand at first, but this is like you are providing a function/lambda that is a method of `ImageRequest.Builder`. Or in other words: your lambda receives one additional parameter of type `ImageRequest.Builder` and it is available in the lambda as `this`.

You can provide `requestBuilder` as any other lambda, but note that inside it you will have access to properties and methods of `ImageRequest.Builder` object that was provided to you.

Comment: You're right. It's tricky to understand. In essence A.(B) -> C means that you use "this" inside the lambda body to reference A while B is just another parameter. Not sure I understand what benefit this has over just defining A and B as two parameters .

Comment: This is much easier to understand when you realize that `this` is just a regular parameter, not really much different than other params. Benefit is the same as in any other function - we can access props/functions of `this` without explicitly referencing it with e.g.: `this.foo`. This pattern is often used in Kotlin with builders or DSLs. In Java we used so called "fluent API": `MyClass.builder().foo(1).bar(2).build()`. In Kotlin it would be: `myObject { foo = 1; bar = 2 }`. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html , especially HTML example seems magic at first. @AndroidDev

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a "function literal with receiver". Speaking generically, a type `A.(B) -> C` represents a function that can be called on a receiver object of A with a parameter of B and return a value of C. Or in your example:

> requestBuilder: (ImageRequest.Builder.(size: IntSize) -> ImageRequest.Builder)?

We have a function `requestBuilder` which can be called on a `ImageRequest.Builder` with a parameter `size: IntSize` and returns another `ImageRequest.Builder`.

Calling this function is just like calling any other function with a lambda as a parameter. The difference: You have access to `ImageRequest.Builder` as `this` inside your lambda block.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following example helps understand lambdas with receiver type:

```
data class Person(val name: String)

fun getPrefixSafely(
    prefixLength: Int,
    person: Person?,
    getPrefix: Person.(Int) -> String): String
{
    if (person?.name?.length ?: 0 < prefixLength) return ""
    return person?.getPrefix(prefixLength).orEmpty()
}

// Here is how getPrefixSafely can be called
getPrefixSafely(
    prefixLength = 2,
    person = Person("name"),
    getPrefix = { x -> this.name.take(x) }
)
```

> How do I implement the requestBuilder parameter?

Hope this part of the code snippet answers the above:
`getPrefix = { x -> this.name.take(x) }`

**PS:** These lambdas with receiver types are similar to extension functions IMO.